# mapbox android navigation is crashing when shouldsimulate is false

Tags: android, navigation, mapbox

Hi i want to launch a navigation in android through mapbox 
the app crash on my phone when

```
shouldSimulateRoute(false)
```

when its true it works

in the emulator the app is rerouting and nothing happens(the arrow is located in california) 
and on the phone(with an apk) the app crash and restart , and then the second time it crashes and closes the app

here is the version that i use

```
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.42.3'
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:8.5.0'
```

here is my code

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.text.style.AbsoluteSizeSpan;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.IdRes;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate;
import androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout;

import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.mapbox.api.directions.v5.models.BannerInstructions;
import com.mapbox.api.directions.v5.models.DirectionsResponse;
import com.mapbox.api.directions.v5.models.DirectionsRoute;
import com.mapbox.geojson.Point;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.camera.CameraPosition;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.geometry.LatLng;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.NavigationView;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.NavigationViewOptions;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.OnNavigationReadyCallback;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.listeners.BannerInstructionsListener;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.listeners.InstructionListListener;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.listeners.NavigationListener;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.listeners.SpeechAnnouncementListener;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.map.NavigationMapboxMap;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.voice.SpeechAnnouncement;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.v5.navigation.NavigationRoute;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.v5.routeprogress.ProgressChangeListener;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.v5.routeprogress.RouteProgress;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnNavigationReadyCallback,
        NavigationListener, ProgressChangeListener, InstructionListListener, SpeechAnnouncementListener,
        BannerInstructionsListener {

    private static final Point ORIGIN = Point.fromLngLat(-77.03194990754128, 38.909664963450105);
    private static final Point DESTINATION = Point.fromLngLat(-77.0270025730133, 38.91057077063121);
    private static final int INITIAL_ZOOM = 16;

    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private View spacer;
    private TextView speedWidget;

    private  String authKey;
    private  String missionId;
    private  Double lngOrigin;
    private  Double latOrigin;
    private  Double lngDest;
    private  Double latDest;
    private static ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    private FloatingActionButton fabNightModeToggle;

    private boolean bottomSheetVisible = true;
    private boolean instructionListShown = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_NoActionBar);
        initNightMode();
        getCoordinates();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Mapbox.getInstance(this, "pk.eyJ1Ijoic2NobWVtNTUiLCJhIjoiY2syZDVjcGVmMDd2YzNpdGRrYWNneThxYSJ9.f0u1jB1HMxihXqAmHfVe7g");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
        fabNightModeToggle = findViewById(R.id.fabToggleNightMode);
        speedWidget = findViewById(R.id.speed_limit);
        spacer = findViewById(R.id.spacer);
        setSpeedWidgetAnchor(R.id.summaryBottomSheet);

        CameraPosition initialPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(ORIGIN.latitude(),ORIGIN.longitude()))
                .zoom(INITIAL_ZOOM)
                .build();
        navigationView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        navigationView.initialize(this, initialPosition);
    }

    private void getCoordinates() {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        lngOrigin = intent.getDoubleExtra("LONGITUDE_ORIGIN_POINT",0);
        latOrigin = intent.getDoubleExtra("LATITUDE_ORIGIN_POINT",0);
        lngDest = intent.getDoubleExtra("LONGITUDE_DESTINATION_POINT",0);
        latDest = intent.getDoubleExtra("LATITUDE_DESTINATION_POINT",0);

    }


    @Override
    public void onNavigationReady(boolean isRunning) {
//        HomeActivity activity = new HomeActivity();
//        Intent intent = getIntent();
//        activity.missionId = missionId = intent.getStringExtra("MISSION_ID");
//        activity.authKey =  intent.getStringExtra("AUTHORIZATION_KEY");
//        activity.latDest= intent.getDoubleExtra("LATITUDE_DESTINATION_POINT",0);
//        activity.lngDest=intent.getDoubleExtra("LONGITUDE_DESTINATION_POINT",0);
//        executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(activity::postCoordinates, 10, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        fetchRoute();
    }

    private void postCoordinates() {
        NavigationMapboxMap map = navigationView.retrieveNavigationMapboxMap();

        String userLat = String.valueOf(map.retrieveMap().getLocationComponent().getLastKnownLocation().getLatitude());
        String userLng =  String.valueOf(map.retrieveMap().getLocationComponent().getLastKnownLocation().getLongitude());

        String data = "\t{\n" +
                "\t\"mission_id\":"+missionId+",\n" +
                "\t\"depart_lat\":"+userLat+",\n" +
                "\t\"depart_lon\":"+userLng+",\n" +
                "\t\"destination_lon\":"+lngDest+",\n" +
                "\t\"destination_lat\":"+latDest+"\n" +
                "\t}";
        URL obj = null;
        HttpURLConnection con = null;
        try {
            obj = new URL("https://some url");
            con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authKey);

        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        OutputStream os = null;
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        try {
            os = con.getOutputStream();
            os.write(data.getBytes());
            os.flush();
            os.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int responseCode = 0;

        try {
            responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        navigationView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        navigationView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        navigationView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
// If the navigation view didn't need to do anything, call super
        if (!navigationView.onBackPressed()) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        navigationView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        navigationView.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        navigationView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        navigationView.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        navigationView.onDestroy();
        if (isFinishing()) {
            saveNightModeToPreferences(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_AUTO);
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_AUTO);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelNavigation() {
// Navigation canceled, finish the activity
        finish();
    }

    public void finishNavigation (View v){
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationFinished() {
// Intentionally empty
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationRunning() {
// Intentionally empty
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChange(Location location, RouteProgress routeProgress) {
        setSpeed(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInstructionListVisibilityChanged(boolean shown) {
        instructionListShown = shown;
        speedWidget.setVisibility(shown ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        if (instructionListShown) {
            fabNightModeToggle.hide();
        } else if (bottomSheetVisible) {
            fabNightModeToggle.show();
            fabNightModeToggle.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public SpeechAnnouncement willVoice(SpeechAnnouncement announcement) {
        return SpeechAnnouncement.builder().announcement("All announcements will be the same.").build();
    }

    @Override
    public BannerInstructions willDisplay(BannerInstructions instructions) {
        return instructions;
    }

    private void startNavigation(DirectionsRoute directionsRoute) {
        NavigationViewOptions.Builder options =
                NavigationViewOptions.builder()
                        .navigationListener(this)
                        .directionsRoute(directionsRoute)
                        .shouldSimulateRoute(false)
                        .progressChangeListener(this)
                        .instructionListListener(this)
                        .speechAnnouncementListener(this)
                        .bannerInstructionsListener(this);
        setBottomSheetCallback(options);
        setupNightModeFab();

        navigationView.startNavigation(options.build());
    }

    private void fetchRoute() {
        //Point origin = Point.fromLngLat(lngOrigin, latOrigin);
        //Point destination = Point.fromLngLat(lngDest, latDest);

        NavigationRoute.builder(this)
                .accessToken(Mapbox.getAccessToken())
                .origin(ORIGIN)
                .destination(DESTINATION)
                .alternatives(true)
                .build()
                .getRoute(new Callback<DirectionsResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Response<DirectionsResponse> response) {
                        DirectionsRoute directionsRoute = response.body().routes().get(0);
                        startNavigation(directionsRoute);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });
    }

    /**
     * Sets the anchor of the spacer for the speed widget, thus setting the anchor for the speed widget
     * (The speed widget is anchored to the spacer, which is there because padding between items and
     * their anchors in CoordinatorLayouts is finicky.
     *
     * @param res resource for view of which to anchor the spacer
     */
    private void setSpeedWidgetAnchor(@IdRes int res) {
        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) spacer.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.setAnchorId(res);
        spacer.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }

    private void setBottomSheetCallback(NavigationViewOptions.Builder options) {
        options.bottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                switch (newState) {
                    case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN:
                        bottomSheetVisible = false;
                        fabNightModeToggle.hide();
                        setSpeedWidgetAnchor(R.id.recenterBtn);
                        break;
                    case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED:
                        bottomSheetVisible = true;
                        break;
                    case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING:
                        if (!bottomSheetVisible) {
// View needs to be anchored to the bottom sheet before it is finished expanding
// because of the animation
                            fabNightModeToggle.show();
                            setSpeedWidgetAnchor(R.id.summaryBottomSheet);
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        return;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
            }
        });
    }

    private void setupNightModeFab() {
        fabNightModeToggle.setOnClickListener(view -> toggleNightMode());
    }

    private void toggleNightMode() {
        int currentNightMode = getCurrentNightMode();
        alternateNightMode(currentNightMode);
    }

    private void initNightMode() {
        int nightMode = retrieveNightModeFromPreferences();
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(nightMode);
    }

    private int getCurrentNightMode() {
        return getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode
                & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK;
    }

    private void alternateNightMode(int currentNightMode) {
        int newNightMode;
        if (currentNightMode == Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES) {
            newNightMode = AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO;
        } else {
            newNightMode = AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES;
        }
        saveNightModeToPreferences(newNightMode);
        recreate();
    }

    private int retrieveNightModeFromPreferences() {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        return preferences.getInt(getString(R.string.current_night_mode), AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_AUTO);
    }

    private void saveNightModeToPreferences(int nightMode) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putInt(getString(R.string.current_night_mode), nightMode);
        editor.apply();
    }

    private void setSpeed(Location location) {
        String string = String.format("%d\nMPH", (int) (location.getSpeed() * 2.2369));
        int mphTextSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.mph_text_size);
        int speedTextSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.speed_text_size);

        SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(string);
        spannableString.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(mphTextSize),
                string.length() - 4, string.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

        spannableString.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(speedTextSize),
                0, string.length() - 3, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

        speedWidget.setText(spannableString);
        if (!instructionListShown) {
            speedWidget.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

here is the activity_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_rounder_corner"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:onClick="finishNavigation"
        android:text="@string/button"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/navigationView"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center"
        app:navigationLightTheme="@style/MyCustomTheme"
        app:navigationDarkTheme="@style/NavigationViewDark"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabToggleNightMode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|start"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/spacer"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end"
        />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/speed_limit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/spacer"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/spacer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="6dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: crashes with what stack trace?

Comment: no its written rerouting on the screen  and nothing in logs

Comment: If it crashes a stacktrace will be printed in the logcat output of Android Studio. Please attach your physical device to Android Studio and reproduce the crash. Then please provide the stack trace of the crash.

Comment: The thing is now that the app not crashes anymore but when i download an apk on my phone the user indicator not moving and is located in California , i changed the source code above